# Xgboost GPU Memory Allocation Error due to large dataset. Which option (xgb_mode, DeviceQuantileDMatrix, Distributed Method) is better to handle this?

Tags: python, machine-learning, gpu, out-of-memory, xgboost

My Training dataset is huge. That is why It is giving a memory allocation error.

**For XGBClassifer:**

I found that I might try a few things:

a) Use **xgb_model** parameter - file name of stored XGBoost model or ‘Booster’ instance XGBoost model to be loaded before training (allows training continuation).
(But NOT Sure - fitting multiple times will give the same results compare to single time)

b) DeviceQuantileDMatrix on a single GPU

c) Distributed - Ray or Dask

My questions:

1. Could anyone share your experience about - is it possible to get the same results with a, b, and c compared to a trained model using whole data at once.?
2. Among these three options (a, b, c), which one will be the best option?

Please help.